# Failed to show admob interstitial when entering foreground from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, admob

Using the iOS example project 2.5: http://google-mobile-dev.googlecode.com/files/InterstitialExample_iOS_2.5.zip

In the `MainController.m`, I add two methods in order to invoke the `showInterstitial` such that every time when the app enter foreground from background, e.g.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillEnterForegroundNotification) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}

- (void) appWillEnterForegroundNotification{        
    [self showInterstitial:nil];
}
```

The first method is for registration the callback for the view controller to receive enter foreground notification, and the second method invoke the `showInterstitial` method when that happen. I can see the method `showInterstitial` is really called and request really fired, but there is no success or error callback being invoked.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's probably not the right time to display the interstitial. You want the application to be active again, not about to be active.

Try it from `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`

Comment: You saved my day, I wanna kiss you <3